# Inserting values to a multidimensional-vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, wxwidgets

I've got a minor problem.

I'm using multidimensional-vectors and I want to insert some values to it at a given position. I'm making a sudoku in wxWidgets and i'm getting the tiles the player have put in and wanting to store them in my mVector.

The mVector looks like this.

```
vector< vector<string> > board{9, vector<string>(9)};
```

And at first i've added values just like this.

```
board[row][col] = value;
```

"value" is a string and row/col are ints.

Is this a legit way of adding values to the mVector? I'm asking this because when I update the board, by doing this above, I for some reason can't run my other functions where i'm solving the board, giving a hint to the board and so on. Before i store the new values to it all the functions works correkt. Do I maby need to use some other type of build in functions for the vector like insert, push_back or something instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you declared the vector as size 9x9, yes that is a valid way of assigning values.

Otherwise you could declare the board as

```
vector<vector<string>> board;
```

Then fill it with

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    vector<string> row;
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
    {
        row.push_back(value);  // where value is whatever you want
    }
    board.push_back(row);
}
```

But again, once the board is of size 9x9, you can simply assign a value at any cell for example

```
board[2][4] = "hello";
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/YJtRuN)