# Set element in two dimentional std::vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, std

I have to replace element at (i,j) position, but that doesn't work. What is the correct way to replace an object in two-dimentional std::vector?

Here is my code:

```
//Call from main



Matrix  *matrixA = new Matrix(5, 5);
matrixA->displayElements();
matrixA->setElement(2, 2, 40.0);
matrixA->displayElements();

//Matrix class
std::vector < std::vector < double >> container;

void Matrix::setElement(long atRow, long atColumn, double value)
{
    for (int i=0; i < this->numberOfColumns; i++)
    {
        std::vector<double> row = this->container.at(i);
        for (int j = 0; j<this->numberOfRows; j++)
        {
            if((j==atRow) && (i == atColumn))
            {
                //std::vector<double> column = this->container.at(i);
                row.insert(row.begin()+j, value);
                std::cout <<row.at(j);
                //int i = 0;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `container[atRow][atColumn] = value;`

Comment: Although not directly related to the question, you should consider using a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`) to manage the `Matrix` object.

Comment: @AlejandroLucena Why use a pointer at all?

Comment: @juanchopanza He may have a reason for allocating `Matrix` on the heap ( not the `std::vector`).

Comment: @AlejandroLucena I very seriously doubt there is a good reason.

Comment: @juanchopanza Perhaps there isn't a good reason, you're absolutely right. But in the case that there were a good reason, I was simply suggesting to use unique_ptr / shared_ptr over manually managing the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way if you want to avoid catching exceptions (for whatever reason) is to just check the boundaries yourself, but there's no need to use loops for it either.
For example:

```
typedef vector<vector<double>> Matrix;
typedef vector<double>::size_type mat_size;

void changeMat(Matrix &mat, mat_size i, mat_size j, double val){
    if(i<mat.size() && j<mat[i].size()){
        mat[i][j] = val;
    }
}
```

As you can see in this [example](http://ideone.com/G72haT) bad access will just fail silently (not saying it's the better way necessarily, but it's another valid way and I'm not sure what you're after).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any loops. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) provides element access via `operator[]`. So, provided your vector has the right dimensions, you can set the element like this:

```
void Matrix::setElement(long atRow, long atColumn, double value)
{
    container[atRow][atColumn] = value;
}
```

This operator does not perform bounds checking, so if you call it with an invalid index, you get *undefined behaviour*. There is also a member function `at()`, which checks bounds and raises an exception for out of bounds access. You can use it thus:

```
container.at(atRow).at(atColumn) = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a new element at position specified by variables atRow and atColumn

then you can do this the following way

```
if ( atRow >= 0 && atRow < this->numberOfRows &&
     atColumn >= 0 && atColumn < this->numberOfColumns )
{
    this->container[atRow].insert( this->container[atRow].begin() + atColumn, value );
}
```

If you want to replace a value then you can write simply

```
if ( atRow >= 0 && atRow < this->numberOfRows &&
     atColumn >= 0 && atColumn < this->numberOfColumns )
{
    this->container[atRow][atColumn] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Vladimir Staxhilov.

The easiest way of adding something to the vector is to have two for-loops that go through the vector and then just add stuff to it. For example.

```
for(int row=0...){
 for(int col=0...){

   if((row==atRow) && (col == atColumn)){
     container[row][col] = "value";
   }

 }
}
```

Here is a similar question I asked a couple of weeks ago. I hope it helps.

[THE LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742392/inserting-values-to-a-multidimensional-vector-in-c)

Comment: Why on earth would you need two for loops?